# Algorithm for summing up elements in unsorted array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I have two arrays:

- Array *A* = [*a*<sub>1</sub>, *a*<sub>2</sub>, …, *a*<sub>*n*</sub>] is unsorted.
- Array *B* = [*b*<sub>1</sub>, *b*<sub>2</sub>, …, *b*<sub>*k*</sub>] is sorted, and has many fewer elements than *A* (that is: *k* ≪ *n*).

For each *b*<sub>*i*</sub>, I want to compute the sum of the greatest *b*<sub>*i*</sub> elements in array A. For example, if

- *A* = [10, 5, 3, 9, 8, 15, 4, 7, 11, 1, 20, 6]
- *B* = [2, 3, 4, 6, 7]

then I want the sums of the 2, 3, 4, 6, and 7 largest elements in *A*:

- [20+15, 20+15+11, 20+15+11+10, 20+15+11+10+9+8, 20+15+11+10+9+8+7]
- that is: [35, 46, 56, 73, 80]

I know how to compute the sum of the *b*<sub>*i*</sub> greatest elements in O(*n*) time, so I can easily write an algorithm for the whole thing that runs in O(*nk*) time; but I need an algorithm that runs in O(*n* log *k*) time.

So, how can I do this in O(*n* log *k*) time?

Comment: @AD.Net . . . Because O(n log k) is faster, and that is typically desirable.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, thanks, got it.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want to find the k largest elements in the first array.

Here is the sketch of the algorithm.  You walk through the first array.  You insert the elements into a data structure -- let's say a b-tree.  Inserts into the data structure are log(k) because the data structure structure is limited to k elements.  So, for the k+1 record, the insert is a bit different because a larger value will overwrite a smaller value.  (There are better data structures than a b-tree, such as a heap, but you might be more familiar with a tree.)

In any case, insertion into this data structure is log(k).  You create it in O(n * log(k)) operations.  Then, you are just need to read the data structure, which is k.  Because k < n, it doesn't contribute to the complexity.  So, this is how you would construct such an algorithm.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in O(nlogk) time without using another data structure? I was given the hint to start with the middle element in array B.

Comment: @Baekyeon . . . I would think you would start with the largest element, because the rest are subsets of that solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not good in writing a complete algorithm. I'll try to illustrate my idea using your example:

Start with middle element of B (4) we found 10+15+11+20=56 as well as splitting A into

```
[10,15,11,20]  [5,3,9,8,4,7,1,6]
```

and B split into

```
[2,3]  [6,7]
```

Recursively we have two reduced summing up problem of:

```
Q1: A' = [10,15,11,20]      B' = [2,3]
Q2: A' = [5,3,9,8,4,7,1,6]  B' = [6-4, 7-4]
```

Take the middle element of B' of Q1 and Q2, each processing A' of Q1 and Q2 respectively. Total number of elements visited among all A' of the sub-problems is still O(n), and we continue to break down the problem into smaller sub-problem, until log(k) times.

There may be some operation to sum up the values in O(k). Since k << n (as defined in the question), this O(k) maybe ignored in compare with the O(n log k) time complexity.